# Stop Counting NULL Values in Case Query

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

The query below is counting 'defects' in data for me, meaning any time when the EncounterID matches but other columns do not. How can I modify the query to not include any 'defects' caused by NULL values?

```
   SELECT FacilityCode,
          AdmitDate,
   SUM(CASE
         WHEN NumFirstName <> 1 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END) AS DifferentFirstNames,
   SUM(CASE
         WHEN NumLastName <> 1 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END) AS DifferentLastNames,
   SUM(CASE
         WHEN NumPhone <> 1 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END) AS DifferentPhone,
        'Defect' Label
   FROM   (SELECT EncounterId,
           FacilityCode,
           AdmitDate,
           COUNT(*)                           AS Num,
           COUNT(DISTINCT LEFT(FirstName, 4)) AS NumFirstName,
           COUNT(DISTINCT LastName)           AS NumLastName,
           COUNT(DISTINCT Phone)              AS NumPhone,
    FROM   [BINextGen].[dbo].[tbFCCDefectReport]
    GROUP  BY EncounterId,
              facilitycode,
              AdmitDate) e
    GROUP  BY FacilityCode,
              AdmitDate;
```

Here is what the current situation looks like:

Sample Data:

```
FacilityCode     AdmitDate     FirstName              LastName
BOHG             7-1-15        Justin                 Kelley
BOHG             7-1-15        Justin                 NULL
AARD             7-1-15        James                  Smith
AARD             7-1-15        James                  Smith
```

Sample Output:

```
FacilityCode     AdmitDate     DifferentFirstNames    DifferentLastNames
BOHG             7-1-15        0                      1
AARD             7-1-15        0                      0
```

I would like to ignore the first last name change because it is NULL and have all 0s in the output (I only care if there is a change such as Kelley changing to Kelly):

Desired Output:

```
FacilityCode     AdmitDate     DifferentFirstNames    DifferentLastNames
BOHG             7-1-15        0                      0
AARD             7-1-15        0                      0
```

Answer (score 0):

In your nested `SELECT` statement you can put a `WHERE` clause specifying to only select if the column isn't `NULL`.

E.g.:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT Phone)              AS NumPhone,
    FROM   [BINextGen].[dbo].[tbFCCDefectReport]
    WHERE LastName IS NOT NULL
    GROUP  BY EncounterId,
              facilitycode,
```